# Sendkeys muy lento en Selenium Python

Tags: python, scraping, pycharm

Hola a todos estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto para raspar una pagina web que usa como navegador Internet Explore, y me he encontrado con lo siguiente estoy tratando de enviarle un texto mediante sendkeys a una caja de texto, pero esta demora alreddor de 6 segundos por palabra es decir mi texto es de 8 caracteres y me tarda 6 segundos por cada uno de ellos 48 segundos en total, no tengo ningun Sleep implementado hasta ahorita asi que no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal o si es problema del navegador, ya que si copio los datos manualmente este lo acepta inmediatamente.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


IEExplorer = webdriver.IeOptions()

driver=webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r"C:\Users\daniel\PycharmProjects\PermitScraping\driver\IEDriverServer.exe")
url = "miURL"
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element(By.NAME,'PermitNumber').send_keys('RP811869')
driver.find_element(By.NAME,'submit').click()
driver.close()
```

Despues de esto no encuentro como enviar el clic al boton de la pagina, al inspeccionarla me aparece como lo muestra la imagen no tiene un Id haci que estoy tratando enviar el click al texto Submit.

[image: Scrap]

Answer (score 1):

El problema con la demora en el envio de string por sendkeys, era derivado al uso del Driver para IE de 64BITS, cambie al Driver de 32BITS y el problema fue solucionado, aunque tambien podria a ver habilitado los proceso de 64BITS en las opciones de IE.

Ahora solo tengo problemas para hacer clic al boton dentro del formulario mismo que esta dentro de una tabla, pero en la tabla no veo el ID o clase del boton, alguna idea de como solucionar el problema?

[image: ClicBtn]